# How to Post Action automatically in php?

Tags: php, post-redirect-get, curl-commandline

Details are here:
First i will hit on this link eg. *http://your.app/callback?**code**=abc123*
then i will receive value from **code** variable from url then i want to redirect this url as a POST action in *https://api.another.com/token
     grant_type=authorization_code&
     code=[**CODE**]* url, bearing the value of **code**

Comment: you can use curl or file_get_contents

Answer (score 0):

Use Curl:

An example:

```
<?php

// if you get the code here from the url,
$code = $_GET['code'];

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://api.another.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "token_grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + $code);

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

?>
```